# Split ID adding hyphen in different positions

Tags: php, function

I need add - in specific positions of ID, i've tried but only works for numbers and don't work for numbers and letters.

I have this: 93e6276537d438fbb4fdb55415afe13d and i need something like:

93e6276-537d-438f-bb4f-db55415afe13d

Add - after position 8 and after position 12, position 16 and 20.

Many thanks

Comment: Note: Depending on how you plan on using your UUID, you could just directly parse your current string into binary form using `$bin = pack("h*", $guid);`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Your dupe gives the java equivalent of my answer, is there one that does it in PHP?

Comment: @Nick Most likely the OP doesn't even want to be doing this.  It is preferable to store a UUID as a byte array in a database, not as a string with hyphens.

Comment: Hi have this: ` <?php

$ids="93e6276537d438fbb4fdb55415afe13d";

 function convertids($ids) {
   
   return preg_replace('/^(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.*)$/', '$1-$2-$3-$4-$5', $ids);
   
 
    }
  
  echo convertids($ids), "\n";
  

?>`, I need tou pass value to new variable, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to split the string based on the lengths of the segments:

```
echo preg_replace('/^(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.*)$/', '$1-$2-$3-$4-$5', '93e6276537d438fbb4fdb55415afe13d');
```

Output:

```
93e62765-37d4-38fb-b4fd-b55415afe13d
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/chkSZ)

Comment: Hi have this: ` <?php $ids="93e6276537d438fbb4fdb55415afe13d"; function convertids($ids) { return preg_replace('/^(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.*)$/', '$1-$2-$3-$4-$5', $ids); } echo convertids($ids), "\n"; ?>`, I need tou pass value to new variable, any idea?

Comment: something ilke `$new_ids = convertids($ids); echo $new_ids`?

Comment: Thanks Nick again